# How to determine the magnitude of a resultant vector?

Tags: physics, vector-analysis

I was able to determine a resultant vector based on the sum of two vectors and told to express them in vector units.  Here is my answer that was correct:

$\overrightarrow{C}=12.01\hat{i}+14.62\hat{j}$

I was told to then determine the magnitude of $\overrightarrow{C}$ but have no idea what to do.

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if $\vec{x} = a\vec{i}+b\vec{j}$, then the magnitude of $\vec{x}$, denoted $\lVert \vec{x}\rVert,$ is given by $\lVert \vec{x}\rVert = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. Does this help?

Comment: Yes! Thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome!